# How to source .bashrc file directly after I close and save?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, configuration

For example, I have a function in my `.bashrc` file:

```
function open_bashrc() {
    gedit ~/.bashrc
    source ~/.bashrc
}
```

So anywhere I am, if I type `open_bashrc`, then it will open the `.bashrc` file. I can open it and change it, but after I save and click close, it doesn't do the second step `source .bashrc`. Rather I have to type `source ~/.bashrc` myself. Why? What's wrong with the function?

Comment: Shouldn't it be (in the function) `source ~/.bashrc` or `source $HOME/.bashrc` to ensure it does it from anyplace you edit?

Comment: Seems like a good Answer, KevinO!

Comment: @KevinO I tried that but that didn't seem to work either. Basically after I run open_bashrc, gedit opens, and once I close the file, the function stops so I don't even think it reaches the next line

Comment: How exactly are you testing the edits? In using the function as described above (with the modification to the source) with gedit, and adding an `export GO=TEAM`, it adds the expected variable. What does `type -f gedit` reveal? And please clarify the statement that the "function stops" since to me that would imply the shell was locked as the function never returned.

Comment: I can not make the function fail to correctly source the file edited. Please note: in the present running shell !. How do you detect the sourcing has failed?

Comment: Try doing `set -x` to enable the debug trace, and then run `open_bashrc` to see what exactly happens. Note that the output can be polluted by the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this in my aliases file and it works:

`alias bashrc='vim ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc'`

Comment: @polvoazul : Whether you have it in an alias or in a shell function, doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be, that in your execution context, `gedit` is not resolved as the executable gedit program, but as a shell script, function or alias, which executes gedit in the **background**? Otherwise, I see no reason, why *source* should not be executed.

Actually, I would not use `&&`, as polvoazul suggested. This solution would have the effect, that the .bashrc is sourced only if gedit returns with exit code zero. While we certainly should hope, that a well-behaved program should exit with 0 if everything went well, I have seen more enought programs which don't care about exit codes, and the man page of gedit is silent about the exit code, which, technically, means that the exit code is unspecified. This is not something I would like my functions to depend on....

Comment: What do you mean executes in the background? If I type in `gedit ~/.bashrc` in terminal, then at that very moment, terminal stops taking commands, and waits till I physically close out of gedit and then it can resume. Is this counted as background?

Comment: No, in this case, it's not background, and the source command must have been executed. Did you try to turn on tracing (`set -x`) inside the function?

Comment: I'm really just have the line that polvoazul provided me in my .bashrc file, nothing more

Comment: In defense of &&: I actually want to source the file ONLY if vim exited correctly. Imagine if it crashes for any reason, better not to source a file in a mid-edit state! Also, I don't know of any code editor that doesn't respect 0 = OK status code.